# MIMEParsingException in REST

Tags: java, rest, netbeans6.8

I have a question about MIMEParsingException.
I use Java EE 6 with NetBeans 6.8. I write a simple REST web service in Java to print "hello world", it runs well. 
Then I write a REST web services client (Java Main Class) to test REST :

public class HelloWorldClient {

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
    Client client = Client.create(config);
    WebResource service = client.resource(getBaseURI());
    String xml = service.path("resources").path("helloworld").accept(MediaType.TEXT_XML).get(String.class);
    System.out.println(xml);
}

private static URI getBaseURI() {
    return UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost:8080/HelloWorldApplication").build();
}
```

}

It complies without error, but when I run it, it throws MIMEParsingException at this line :
Client client = Client.create(config);

Exception in thread "main" com.sun.jersey.spi.service.ServiceConfigurationError: jersey-client-components: A dependent class, org/jvnet/mimepull/MIMEParsingException, of the class com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.MultiPartReader implementing the provider class java.lang.Object is not found. The provider implementation is ignored.
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.service.ServiceFinder.fail(ServiceFinder.java:388)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.service.ServiceFinder.access$200(ServiceFinder.java:144)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.service.ServiceFinder$LazyClassIterator.next(ServiceFinder.java:595)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.service.ServiceFinder$LazyClassIterator.next(ServiceFinder.java:571)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.service.ServiceFinder.toClassArray(ServiceFinder.java:374)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.(Client.java:167)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.(Client.java:139)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.create(Client.java:466)
        at helloWorld.client.HelloWorldClient.main(HelloWorldClient.java:29)

Who can resolve this problem ? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing a [dependency](https://jersey.dev.java.net/source/browse/*checkout*/jersey/tags/jersey-1.1.2-ea/jersey/dependencies.html):

> Non-maven developers require:
>
> [mimepull.jar](http://download.java.net/maven/2/org/jvnet/mimepull/1.3/mimepull-1.3.jar),
>   [jersey-multipart.jar](http://download.java.net/maven/2/com/sun/jersey/contribs/jersey-multipart/1.1.2-ea/jersey-multipart-1.1.2-ea.jar)

Comment: Thank you very much. I added these two jars in my project, and it runs well now.