# Phonegap upload pictures multipart/form-data - iPad application- Worklightv6 - WAS

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm trying to upload pictures using PhoneGap under an ipad Application (using worklightV6) to a Websphere Application Server in a RestFul API.

my web browser code looks like this :

```
var photosURI = [];
var manageDeviceDocumentsURI = "http://IP:PORT/****/rest/AmanageDevicesDocuments.upload";

function cameraSuccessCallback(imageURI){
   photosURI.push(imageURI);
}

$("#content").on("click", "#takePicture", function(){
   cameraOptions = {quality : 20, allowEdit: true, desinationType.FILE_URI };
   navigator.camero.getPicture(cameraSuccessCallback, cammeraErrorCallback, cameraOptions);
});

$("#content").on("click", "#uploadPictures", function(){

   function fail(error){
     alert("An error has occured: Code " + error.code);
     console.log("Upload error source " + error.source);
     console.log("Upload error target " + error.target); 
   }

   function win(){
     alert('transfert ok');
   }

   var fileURI = photosURI.pop();
   var options = new FileUploadOptions();
   options.fileKey = "file";
   options.fileName = fileURI.substr(fileURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
   options.mimeType = "multipart/form-data";

   var ft = new FileTransfert();
   ft.upload(fileURI, encodeURI(manageDeviceDocumentsURI), win, fail, otpions);
});
```

My java code on the server looks like this :

```
@Path("manageDeviceDocuments")
public class ManageDeviceDocuments {

    @POST
    @Path("upload")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public JSONArray upload(@Context ServletConfig servletConfig,
                            @Context HttpHeaders httpHeaders, @Context UriInfo uriInfo,
                            BufferedInMultiPart bimp) throws IOException {

    }

}
```

And i'm getting the following error on the web browser :

> Error 415 : Unsupported Media Type, code 3 ...

And this on the server :

> A message body reader for Java class
>   org.apache.wink.common.model.multipart.BufferedInMultiPart, and Java
>   type class org.apache.wink.common.model.multipart.BufferedInMultiPart,
>   and MIME media type
>   multipart/form-data;boundary=+++++org.apache.cordova.formBoundary was
>   not found. The registered message body readers compatible with the
>   MIME media type are:
>   */* ->   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.MimeMultipartProvider
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$StreamSourceReader
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SAXSourceReader
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$DOMSourceReader
>   com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$General
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootObjectProvider$General
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.EntityHolderReader
>   com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$General
>   com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$General

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: Have you looked at the XHR request being sent out from the phone? Does it look correct? Not familiar with Worklight but I'm curious if everything is looking correct from the phone…

Answer (score 2):

By changing my RestFul API to :

```
@POST 
@Path("upload") 
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA) 
public Response upload(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,@FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) { 

}
```

and the following post [MIMEParsingException in REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975513/mimeparsingexception-in-rest) (I added mimepull.jar, jersey-multipart.jar to my lib path), I managed to make it work !